# Creating a customer Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.0 app with a javascript frontend.
I want to let my users build their own query when fetching a list of projects using a Form interface on the frontend (like filtering).

For example:

```
Select Projects WHERE Status IS "pending" AND Title IS NOT "Building".
```

Or

```
Select Project WHERE Status IS "approved" AND Title IS NULL.
```

Is there a gem I can use? How can I make it dynamic (and safe) in the backend?

Thankful for all help!

**Update**

I think I may have found a solution called Ransack. Good?

http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're looking for a way for users to be able to search on project status you can use a `scope`.  There wasn't much code posted so I don't know what your controller and models are called but I used a Project model as an example.

in your index action add

```
def index
  @projects = Project.all
  if params[:search].present?
    @projects = @projects.by_status_and_title(params[:search])
  end
end
```

in your model create the scope

```
#
    scope :by_status_and_title, ->(title_and_stats) { where('title LIKE ? OR status LIKE ?', "%#{title_and_stats}%","%#{title_and_stats}%" ) if title_and_stats.present? }
```

Or you can create individual scopes

```
scope :by_status, ->(stats) { where('status LIKE ?', "%#{stats}%") }
scope :by_title, ->(t) { where('title LIKE ?', "%#{t}%") }
```

in your view pass the search param to the controller

```
<%= form_tag(some_path, method: 'get', class: 'form-inline justify-content-center') do %>
  <%= search_field_tag 'search', params[:search], class: 'form-control mb-2 mr-sm-3 mb-sm-0 input-width', placeholder: 'Search'  %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block-sm-down', :name => nil %>                        
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! This I can do without a problem. What I am looking for is to allow the users to create their own custom queries where they, via a form, query the DB. For example with multiple selects and booleans and so on.

Answer (score 1):

To have such a in-built queries, You can use [pacecar](https://github.com/thoughtbot/pacecar) gem which provide many functionalities.